# How to position Foundation Dropdown?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5.4.5 dropdown for my login form but the problem is that the dropdown appears like this:

[image]

I want it to be like the one opened where the nub on the right and the body positioned well

[image: What i want]

Here is my HTML:

```
<a data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false">Has Dropdown</a>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I just read foundation.dropdown.js I'm guessing that foundation tries to automatically position/align your dropdown inside the parent <div>. In your case it is smaller than your dropdown so it does an incorrect positioning. Just let me know it this is correct. I made a workaround for this to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

```
<a data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false" data-options="align:left">Has Dropdown</a>
```

Or

```
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown drop-left" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Both work AS WORKAROUNDS. However, I get your point: you want your dropdown to be displayed in the bottom of your link, but aligned with the right border. I would be grateful if someone came up with an answer for that because the foundation site show it is possible in some undocumented way.

Answer (score 0):

To specify how the drop down shows use the align property in data-options on the target element.

Add  `data-options="align:right"`  to the   `a`  tag.

Comment: All customisations for Foundation 5 drop downs found here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html You can either edit the SCSS defaults or override them in your SCSS.